# Quisiera saber como capturo la opcion de un radiobutton para mostrarla en el JTable de este ventana?

Tags: java

//Esta es la ventana donde voy a mostrar un precio segun las opciones del usuario en la ventana principal

```
public class VentanaResultados extends JFrame {

    public VentanaResultados() {

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // Nombres de las columnas 
        final String[] Columnas = {"Familia", "Precio por día"};

        // Datos 
        Object[][] datos = {
            {"", ""}};

        JTable tabla = new JTable(datos, Columnas);

        tabla.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        tabla.setRowHeight(24);

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tabla); // ,ver , hor) ;

        cp.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(500, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para capturar la **opción** de un **JRadioButton**, una de las maneras sería *implementar* de alguna manera la interfaz `ItemListener` el cual tiene como método abstracto `itemStateChanged​(ItemEvent e)`.

Para generar el evento lo haríamos con el **JRadioButton** y el método `addItemListener(ItemListener l);`

```
miRadioButton.addItemListener(new ClaseQueImplementaItemListener());
```

Donde `ClaseQueImplementaItemListener()` sería la **clase receptora** del **evento**.

Y para saber el **radiobutton** exacto presionado.. dentro del método `itemStateChanged`()

```
if (miRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        new VentanaResultados();
}
```

---

También lo **podrías hacer** con una **clase anónima** de esta manera..

```
miRadioButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            new VentanaResultados();
        }
    });
```